# what are root cut nodes,bridge cut nodes, parent cut nodes in finding the aritculation vertices?

Tags: graph, depth-first-search

what are root cut nodes,bridge cut nodes, parent cut nodes in finding the aritculation vertices?
can somebody explain it with examples please.
I am getting confused with the bridge cut nodes in particular.
its defination says

> If the earliest reachable vertex from v is v, then deleting the single
>   edge (parent[v], v) disconnects the graph

How could the earliest reachable vertex from v be v ?

Comment: where did you get that definition?

Comment: I am reading it form skiena's algorithm design manual.It initializes the earliest reachable vertex of each node to itself and after the graph is traversed using dfs if it remains unchanged then its a bridge node.

Comment: Skiena's ADM is usually excellent, but I think it drops the ball in that specific section. It's one of the most convoluted and confusing explanations of the articulation vertex DFS algorithm that I've seen. Root cut-nodes, bridge cut-nodes, parent cut-nodes. What? All you really need to know is that a node N is an AV if any of its direct children has no alternative paths leading back to one of N's ancestors. It's valid for all N, except when N is a leaf or a root with a single child (which technically makes it a leaf).

Comment: Also, I think that a more rigorous explanation of how a node's earliest reachable ancestor (ERA) is determined – that is, by picking the earliest among its own direct ancestors from its back-edges *and* that of its children's ERA – would have been very helpful. From then, the algorithm is a breeze.

Answer (score 7):

Don't know if you still care, but I'm reading the same text right now

**Root Cut-Node**

I think a root cut-node is pretty obvious

**Bridge Cut-Node**

Remember to change v's reachable_ancestor the three following conditions must be met:

- there is an edge (v, y) that is a back edge
- for the edge (v, y), y is not the parent of v
- entry_time of y is before the entry_time of v's reachable_ancestor

So if you look at Figure 5.13 of the book, you'll see that because the one (lower on the tree) bridge-cut node has no parent that is not y, it will never have it's reachable_ancestor changed from the initial reachable_ancestor[v] = v. Which in turn makes it's parent a bridge-cut node and (only because it is not a leaf) makes that node also a bridge-cut node.

**Parent Cut-Node**

The reason in Figure 5.13 that v's parent is a parent cut-node (as opposed to a bridge cut-node) is because bridges must meet the following conditions:

- The edge is a tree edge
- No back edges connect from v or below to y or above

Clearly in the graph, children of v connect back up to it's parent (y) and above, making the edge between v and y not an bridge, but making y still a cut-node.

Hope that helped!

Comment: It is very old question, but I wanted one thing to ensure.  It says, "if the earliest reachable vertex from v is the parent of v ..." . But how reachable vertex from v is parent of v in given example at book?(figure 5.13). To that happen there must be back edge from v and there is not. I am in stuck how process_edge sets reachable  ancestor for v to be its parent. Please enlighten me.

Comment: If you read further in the book, what happens is that the reachable_vertex is backed up to the parent in case the parent's reachable ancestor is later than the child's reachable vertex. Only in this case will reachable_ancestor[y] == parent[y]

Comment: The idea is that if a child can reach an earlier vertex, the parent can do too